# Setting environment variables *for programs run from launchd* under OS X Yosemite

Tags: environment-variables, osx-yosemite

I've learned elsewhere on Stack Exchange that [Apple has removed the formerly preferred way to set environment variables, `/etc/launchd.conf`, from OS X Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26311753/2829764). The Apple rep I linked to and others advise creating a launch agent to set the environment variables. My problem is that I run a number of Python scripts from launchd and I need to set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable for them. The launch agent approach lets me set `PYTHONPATH` for most of what I run, but the change does not seem to percolate into jobs that are run straight from launchd. I have a lot of these jobs, so I don't want to have to set the environment variable I need in the launch agent for each. Is there a way I can make the environment variable change deeply enough that even stuff run from launchd itself picks up the change?

My current workaround is to use a `.pth` file but that only works for Python.

Comment: I don't suppose you ever found a solution to this? It's still a pain in my ass at the moment.