# Strange behaviour for setenv & getenv in OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, setenv, getenv

When I set an environment variable

```
launchctl setenv FOO test
```

I can fetch the value by

```
launchctl getenv FOO
```

which returns me 'test', but a simple

```
echo $FOO
```

doesn't substitute, the result is empty. In same terminal as well as in new terminal.

Background: Yosemite 10.10 doesn't support /etc/launchd.conf anymore for system wide settings, so [Setting environment variables via launchd.conf no longer works in OS X Yosemite/El Capitan/macOS Sierra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385934/setting-environment-variables-via-launchd-conf-no-longer-works-in-os-x-yosemite/26477515#26477515) looks pretty promising, but I need the access to the env vars via `$VARNAME`, which doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Have you tried restarting Terminal.app?

Comment: That was the trick :) I just opened a new tab or window but didn't killed the old Terminal.app before. Now all's fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in section **Issues / problems** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26477515/2078908) in order your env variables were correctly taken by applications after system reboot you will need:

- either login twice: login => logout => login
- or close & re-open applications manually, where env variables should be taken
- or do NOT use feature "Reopen windows when logging back".

This happens due to Apple denies explicit ordering of loaded services, so env variables are registered in parallel with processing of the "reopen queue".

Comment: I even read that couple of times but misunderstood close & re-open for Terminal.app. It's not about closing one terminal window and opening a new one but about quitting Terminal.app as app. Which makes sense afterwards :)