# Access macOS environment variables from Python

Tags: python, environment-variables, launchctl

I got a bunch of environment variables set with the `launchctl` command:

```
launchctl setenv TEST /Users/JohnDoe/Test
```

To get the value back, I can use:

```
launchctl getenv TEST
```

However, I can't access the value of `TEST` from Python, using `os.getenv('TEST')` (or even from Bash using `echo $TEST`). I do know how macOS manages environment variables (the difference between `launchctl` and Bash environment variables, etc.) so I understand why those commands don't return the value of `TEST`.

My question is: is there a way to access environment variables set with `launchctl`, without using `subprocess`? Using `subprocess` is not a no-go, I'd just rather avoid throwing lots of processes just to get environment variables :)

Comment: And you are unable to start the python interpreter in a way that the required environment variables are available to the process?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange behaviour for setenv & getenv in OS X Yosemite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27045137/strange-behaviour-for-setenv-getenv-in-os-x-yosemite)

Comment: @NilsWerner thanks for pointing me to this other issue. I do use the "Reopen windows when logging back" and not planning to stop doing so. So that explains why I can't access the environment variables. I will probably switch to regular Bash variables in that case!