# How to set Environment variables with OS X 10.10

Tags: environment-variables, osx-yosemite

I must be a little slow. I found an answer on here that worked temporarily until I restarted my computer. Now my environment variables are gone. All the answers I've found are for different versions of OS X (which are conveniently all a little different) and none seem to be up to date with OS X 10.10. All I want to do is set my ANDROID_HOME variable for Eclipse. Who would have thought this would be so difficult. What is THE way to permanently set ANDROID_HOME and other environment variables for my Mac.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting environment variables via launchd.conf no longer works in OS X Yosemite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385934/setting-environment-variables-via-launchd-conf-no-longer-works-in-os-x-yosemite)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue like yours. I am not sure how to permanently set an environment variable in Mac OS X 10.10, but I found a workaround that may solve your issue.

Please try to set `ANDROID_HOME` as an environment variable in eclipse.
This is how it's done:

1. select the class you wanna run
2. right click on it
3. go to: run as -> run configurations -> environment
4. here you can add the variable `ANDROID_HOME` with the path to your android sdk