# Why are environment variables always null to Gradle (only) when run from IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, intellij-14

I wrote a task in gradle that grabs an environment variable.

```
task run(type:Exec) {
    def SYS_ENV = System.getenv("SYSTEM_ENV")
    // do something with SYS_ENV 
}
```

If I run this task with `./gradlew :taskName` it's all fine, but if I run the same task from IntelliJ IDEA, (with the [image: https://www.jetbrains.com/img/webhelp/run.png] button, or from the gradle panel) the env variable comes out as `null`.

I tried restarting IntelliJ, I also tried the `Invalidate Caches/Restart` option, but nothing changes.

Isn't IntelliJ IDEA supposed to run the Gradle script exactly like I run it form the command? What can I do to grab an env variable from Grade so that the script doesn't fail when run form IntelliJ?

EDIT: I did a bunch of trials, and I could make `lanchctl setenv MY_PATH MY_VALUE` work, but it's not permanent, and adding `setenv MY_PATH MY_VALUE` to `/etc/lanchd.conf` does not make it so.

Comment: Which OS are you using, and where exactly is the SYSTEM_ENV variable set?

Comment: I'm on OSX Yosemite and I set the variable in ~/.bash_profile

Comment: I believe that is your issue. Environment variables set in *~/.bash_profile* won't be available to GUI applications. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/588442/957630) for more info.

Comment: @Mark Vieira Thanks for that. I'll try as soon as I get to the PC and report back.

Comment: @MarkVieira I tried and it doesn't work on my machine, even thought it seems it should from other posts. Maybe in IntelliJ IDEA 14 something changed, I have no idea. (Yes, I restarted the PC after editing launch.conf)

Comment: `launchct setenv MY_PATH MY_VALUE` works, but it's not permanent...

Comment: I give all the research up. This problem has [precedents](http://emmanuelbernard.com/blog/2012/05/09/setting-global-variables-intellij/), but no solutions. Please, feel free to post an answer if you find one.

Comment: For future reference, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x) is another related question I found.

Comment: As a workaround you could try launching IntelliJ from the terminal.

Comment: It's not really a solution since the goal here is portability (which is what env variables are there for, after all). In other words, it's better to ask a user to hard-code the variable in the script than to ask him to run the IDE form the terminal, I think.

Answer (score 0):

A relatively old question, but the following worked for me on Yosemite (10.10) so answering here in case others have the issue.

Support for `launchd.conf` was removed in Yosemite. LaunchAgents can be used in OSX to start per-user processes. You can use these to re-run the `launchctl` step in your question effectively persisting the environment variable

1. Create a user Launch Agent to set your variables (edit the environment variables and run the following in a terminal window)

   ```
   cat << EOF > ~/Library/LaunchAgents/user.environment.plist
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
     <dict>
       <key>Label</key>
       <string>user.environment</string>
       <key>ProgramArguments</key>
       <array>
         <string>sh</string>
         <string>-c</string>
         <string>launchctl setenv MYPATH MY_VALUE</string>
       </array>
       <key>RunAtLoad</key>
       <true/>
     </dict>
   </plist>
   EOF
   ```
2. Restart your mac
3. Make sure you restart any open applications (e.g. IntelliJ). Just restarting didn't work for me, I needed to close and re-launch the apps.

*References*:

- [Setting environment variables via launchd.conf no longer works in OS X Yosemite/El Capitan/macOS Sierra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385934/setting-environment-variables-via-launchd-conf-no-longer-works-in-os-x-yosemite)
- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html