# How does installers set PATH variable on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, go, terminal, environment-variables

I'm wondering how PATH variable is set by Mac Installers on Mac OSX.

For example:

Look at golang Mac OSX Installer. From the link https://golang.org/doc/install:

> Mac OS X package installer
>
> Download the package file, open it, and follow the prompts to install
>   the Go tools. The package installs the Go distribution to
>   /usr/local/go.
>
> The package should put the /usr/local/go/bin directory in your PATH
>   environment variable. You may need to restart any open Terminal
>   sessions for the change to take effect.

So, the I can see /usr/local/go/bin in $PATH but it's not being set in .profile, .bashrc or launchd.conf.

Can anybody please help me to understand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple methods of setting environment variables in Mac OS X ([lots of discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385934/2167797)). In the case the Go package, it is adding a file in `/etc/paths.d` named `go` that contains `/usr/local/go/bin`. Here's an answer to another question [explaining that a utility called path_helper is being launched](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/106814) and it's inspecting the `/etc/paths.d` directory.

You can verify this yourself by using an application called [Pacifist](https://www.charlessoft.com) to inspect the contents of the Go package and looking at the files it's installing.