# Get Qt5 up and running on a new Mac

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt5, osx-yosemite

Coming from Ubuntu I bought a new iMac and tried to setup my Qt development. Everything else is already up and running. Xcode command line tools are also installed.

Because it surprised me how good `brew`and `brew cask`worked I wanted to install `Qt5`with them. On the one side it is very fast and I do not have to got to any homepage in order to download it. On the other side I do not have to care about the installation directory. Having multiple version installed should also be a lot simpler though.

I used the following commands:

`brew install qt5`

`brew cask install qt-creator`

`Qt5` is now installed under `/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.4.1`. I also added the `bin` folder to my path (done in `.bash_profile`). QtCreator, Linguist and all the other applications are shown in my launchpad. But unfortunately, it is still not done.

`QtCreator` says that no version of Qt is known. I tried to add qmake but I was not able to navigate to the folder mentioned above.

Could anybody give me a hint on how to fix this issue? Installing qt via installer should be the last option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had similar issue with Qt Creator, now on Mac GUI applications do not have access to environmental variables (in previous versions it was different).

You need to setup path to qmake in Qt Creator manually using Command-Shift-G in Finder to navigate to Folder you need.

Comment: Mac applications [do have access to environment variables](http://stackoverflow.com/a/588442/2167797). Just run `launchctl setenv QTDIR /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.4.1` See the link on how to set this permanently.

Comment: It was so in old versions of Mac OS but according to discussions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385934/setting-environment-variables-via-launchd-conf-no-longer-works-in-os-x-yosemite?lq=1 this method is working in some versions of Yosemite but not working in others (10.10.0 and 10.10.1 due to bug)

Comment: This [bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385934/setting-environment-variables-via-launchd-conf-no-longer-works-in-os-x-yosemite?lq=1#comment43575294_25912736)? It only affects the PATH variable. The [LaunchAgents](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26586170/2167797) method seems to set it permanently seems to work fine for Yosemite.

Comment: @Linville Based on the link you shared - I used this to point to new version of Qt(5.5,which I manually moved to  /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/location instead of  4.8.7) . Did the following -: (added to environment.plist)  <string>
    launchctl setenv QTDIR /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.5
    </string> and then launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/environment.plist . On doing qmake --version now, I still see QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.7 in /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/lib - what am I doing wrong ? I am on yosemite 10.10.5.

Answer (score 7):

Another option is to use `brew link qt5 --force`, which will symlink the various `Qt5` binaries and libraries into your `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/lib` directories.  This will give you `qmake` at the command line, without requiring you to add anything special to your path in `.bash_profile`.  The main reason this isn't done by default is that `Qt4` is also somewhat popular.

It could get a little messy, but if you need to install `Qt4` as well, you can unlink `Qt5` at any time, by doing `brew unlink qt5`, and it will keep the installation intact.  Then do `brew install qt` to get `Qt4`, which unlike the brew installation for `Qt5` will indeed create the links directly into `/usr/local` without you having to manually do `brew link qt`.  You can unlink `Qt4` and relink `Qt5` (or vice-versa) whenever you need to switch.

Comment: Brew notes that it is keg-only "because Qt 5 has CMake issues when linked".

Answer (score 0):

In my cases I needed to set it in Preferences => QT Versions => Add. Environment variables also did not help. Small popup when starting app also did not work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use command like this:

```
brew install qt@5
```

and. success install qt5 by brew.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).