# Cannot create Android package with Gradle

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, javafx, javafxports

I made a JavaFX project and I generate a Gradle build file with eclipse. My build file is in /workspace/Puzzle_FX i use the JavaFXPort get started, but when i type `./gradlew android` i got this error :

```
Unzipping /Users/usr/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.12-all/2apkk7d25miauqf1pdjp1bm0uo/gradle-1.12-all.zip to /Users/usr/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.12-all/2apkk7d25miauqf1pdjp1bm0uo
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:164)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:160)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$400(Install.java:29)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:70)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    ... 3 more
```

I install the Android SDK and I use `gradle` command to download all file. I'm working on Mac OS X Yosemite. I installed gradle with brew command. So how can I create my Android apk with gradle to convert my JavaFX project to Android file with JavaFXPort ?

Comment: What gradle version are you using?

Comment: But on your stacktrace it says 1.12...

Comment: I use gradle command and i got this message "Welcome to Gradle 2.3.

To run a build, run gradle <task> ...

To see a list of available tasks, run gradle tasks

To see a list of command-line options, run gradle --help

To see more detail about a task, run gradle help --task <task>

BUILD SUCCESSFUL"

Comment: I will edit my post to show you what did gradle command

Comment: Every JavaFXPorts project has a custom **gradlew** file, not exactly the same as using the default gradle one. The latter should work too. But in this path /Users/usr/.gradle/wrapper/dists/ it should take the 2.3 version. Could you show in your post at what point (which task) does that exception appear?

Comment: Should I show you the line in each files in the exception ?

Comment: No, when you run `gradlew android`, several tasks are executed: :compileJava,  :compileRetrolambdaMain, :processResources, :classes,
:compileAndroidJava, :compileRetrolambdaAndroid... One of those gives that exception.Which one is it?

Comment: I copy/past the gradlew file on post

Comment: That's not what I meant. When you run that file with `android` task, several tasks are performed. One is giving you an exception, can you tell which task is that? Could you post the whole output, not just the exception?

Comment: I don't know where these tasks are performed
By the way all task give me this exception.

Comment: Run again `gradlew android` on command line, and try to post all the output you get. Also you can remove the gradle 2.3 output from your post, it's not relevant.

Comment: when I run `./gradlew android` on command i get the same thing that i post

Comment: Have you added gradle to your path environmental system variable? Maybe it's pointing to that old 1.12 version.

Comment: No I didn't how can I do this ?

Comment: I'm not a Mac user, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385934/setting-environment-variables-via-launchd-conf-no-longer-works-in-os-x-yosemite) may help you.

Comment: Thank you, i will try this after my dinner. But i can use Linux or windows for this if I failed.