# Maven works from terminal, but not from Eclipse in Yosemite

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, environment-variables, osx-yosemite

I recently upgraded to Yosemite and my maven stopped working. I figured that was because my environment variables were not set, so I followed this post and created an environment.plist file.

[Setting environment variables via launchd.conf no longer works in OS X Yosemite/El Capitan/macOS Sierra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385934/setting-environment-variables-via-launchd-conf-no-longer-works-in-os-x-yosemite)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"     "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>my.startup</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>sh</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>
        launchctl setenv M2_HOME /Applications/dev/apache-maven-2.2.1
        launchctl setenv M2 /Applications/dev/apache-maven-2.2.1/bin
        launchctl setenv JAVA_HOME $(/usr/libexec/java_home)
        launchctl setenv PATH /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:$(/usr/libexec/java_home):/Applications/dev/apache-maven-2.2.1/bin
    </string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

But I still get command not found in for Maven, and for some reason $PATH is not set, others are

> MAC-R4498:~ r4498$ mvn --version
>   -bash: mvn: command not found
>
> MAC-R4498:~ r4498$ echo $M2_HOME
>   /Applications/dev/apache-maven-2.2.1
>
> MAC-R4498:~ r4498$ echo $JAVA_HOME
>   /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
>
> MAC-R4498:~ r4498$ echo $PATH
>   /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

So I added $PATH to the ~/.bash_profile

```
export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:$(/usr/libexec/java_home):/Applications/dev/apache-maven-2.2.1/bin"
```

And mvn started working through the terminal

> MAC-R4498:~ r4498$ echo $PATH
>   /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home:/Applications/dev/apache-maven-2.2.1/bin
>
> MAC-R4498:~ r4498$ mvn --version
>   Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 14:16:01-0500)
>   Java version: 1.6.0_65
>   Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
>   Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MacRoman
>   OS name: "mac os x" version: "10.10.3" arch: "x86_64" Family: "mac"

But when I run any maven command from eclipse, I get this

[image]

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: After you made the change the to PATH, did you restart Eclipse?

Comment: What does `which mvn` return?

Comment: Returned /Applications/dev/apache-maven-2.2.1/bin/mvn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This took forever to figure out.

All I had to do was go to Eclipse->Preferences
->Maven->Installations and add a path to my maven directory.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open eclipse from terminal it works for me.