# Go on IntelliJ: missing SDK/environment variables

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, go, environment-variables

I'd like to learn `Go` and attempted to setup the [Go plugin for IntelliJ](http://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin) on IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3. I'm running OSX Yosemite (10.10.3).

I installed go using [Brew](http://brew.sh/): `brew install go`.

I'm unable to setup the SDK as I go through the new project wizard. The Project SDK is empty, when I click 'Configure', and navigate to the `libexec` folder of the installation (`/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/`), the Project SDK never is never displayed in the box. If I click through the wizard, it warns me that no SDK was specified, and then warns that `GOROOT` and `GOPATH` env variables are empty of could not be detected.

It seems there are [quite a few ways to set environment variables on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385934/setting-environment-variables-via-launchd-conf-no-longer-works-in-os-x-yosemite). I created an  `~/Library/LaunchAgents/environment.plist` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>my.startup</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>sh</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>
    launchctl setenv GOROOT "/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/"
    launchctl setenv GOPATH "/Users/awoolford/golang/"
    </string>

  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

If I run `launchctl load -w  ~/Library/LaunchAgents/environment.plist` the environment variables are loaded:

```
$ launchctl getenv GOPATH
/Users/awoolford/golang/

$ launchctl getenv GOROOT
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/
```

I would have expected IntelliJ to recognize these environment variables, and that I'd be able to create a project in `~/golang/`.

Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you running the latest version of the plugin?

Comment: I downloaded version 0.9.15.3 from http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5047.

Comment: Try the beta/alpha version from the github page.

Comment: Thanks @inf. I added the alpha version of the plugin (via https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugins/alpha/5047) and it's working now!