# add /usr/local/bin to $PATH got from System.getenv("PATH") in JAVA run on MAC OS

Tags: macos, path

I manually installed a software which is under /usr/local/bin. I want to use it in Java. But when I use System.getenv("PATH") to get $PATH. it doesn't include /usr/local/bin. How to solve this problem?

$PATH I got from terminal:

```
/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/maven/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

$PATH I got in JAVA run from eclipse:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

My /etc/paths is like this:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

My ~/.bashrc is like this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/maven/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH
```

There is no content in ~/.bash_profile.

Comment: As you can see /usr/local/bin is already in $PATH from terminal, but not in JAVA from eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting environment variables via launchd.conf no longer works in OS X Yosemite/El Capitan

the answer "Create an environment.plist file in ~/Library/LaunchAgents/" doesn't work for me. In OSX 10.10.5
[Setting environment variables via launchd.conf no longer works in OS X Yosemite/El Capitan/macOS Sierra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385934/setting-environment-variables-via-launchd-conf-no-longer-works-in-os-x-yosemite)

Using this method, works for setting other variables but not for PATH. I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the global osx path by adding a line to /etc/launchd.conf and rebooting your computer.

setenv PATH /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
Works in OSX 10.8 and 10.9

https://serverfault.com/questions/16355/how-to-set-global-path-on-os-x/277034#277034