# mac os x system variables for gui applications (finder, xcode, etc.)

Tags: xcode, macos, variables, system

I want to set system variables for GUI pallications (Finder, Xcode, etc.) after reboot computer.
I can to do it for bash(write "export VAR=/path/" to file ~/.profile, and after reboot all bash terminals has these variables), but I have some problems with variables for all GUI applications after reboot computer.
I do it for MAC OS X 10.10 Yosemite.
Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26586170/2836621 This should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem by adding the string `export sys_var=<path>` to the `~/.profile` file.