# MacOS Sierra: modify $PATH globally

Tags: python, macos, environment-variables, macos-sierra

3 scenarios to get $PATH below: 1) from Terminal 2) from Python launched from Terminal 3) from Python (IDLE)

1) In terminal: `>> echo $PATH` leads to the list of ~10-15 locations

2) Run Python in terminal:

```
>> python
>> os.environ['PATH']
>> # I get the same list as in the first scenario. Expected
```

3) Now I run python IDLE (so, don't run Terminal)

```
>> os.environ['PATH']
>> # I get different list of paths. much less locations comparing to 1 or 2 scenarios.
```

Q: how do I change $PATH such that it affects Python IDLE? I found some recommendations to update $PATH from .bash_profile, but looks like they affect $PATH only when I run Terminal.

I also considered /etc/paths, but still there is a location (/usr/loca/bin/) there that is missed in 3d scenario. So what is basically the origin of $PATH variable in Mac OS X?

Comment: This question should have the answers you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385934/setting-environment-variables-via-launchd-conf-no-longer-works-in-os-x-yosemite

Answer (score 1):

The variable $PATH is changed by .bash_profile, which is executed when you start the terminal. In your case, you should edit `/etc/paths.d/` via, for example, the Apple tool `path_helper` (see [here](http://www.softec.lu/site/DevelopersCorner/MasteringThePathHelper)).

Comment: I think you missed the question. IDLE prints different information

Comment: so, actually path_helper does print '/usr/local/bin/' while Python IDLE doesn't. Does it mean that Python IDLE has its own setting or it loads /etc/paths but then removes some locations by some other settings?

Comment: The variable `PATH` is often set by `.bash_profile` but that's *only* for programs that run in the terminal and only if your shell is set to Bash.

Comment: Have you tried to update the PATH variable in the `.profile` file instead of in the `.bash_profile` one?