# Getting Error "Vaadin Designer requires Node to be installed" with Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, vaadin, vaadin10

I recently started learning Vaadin, I installed the Vaadin Designer plugin in IntelliJ IDEA. When I open JS files I'm getting an error like below:

[image]

I'm using nvm for installing node js in my mac. What are the things that I required to configure to get rid of this error?

Comment: Make sure `node` binary is visible to the GUI apps, not just Terminal apps, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26586170/104891.

Comment: I tried everything above, including the environment.plist, but still get the same error. On a terminal, 'which node' shows where my node is located.

Does someone have clear instructions on how to make it work?

To the Vaadin team: as Vaadin now downloads node in ~/.vaadin, could it actually use that copy instead?

Comment: FYI, I finally fixed it using:
sudo launchctl config user path $HOME/.nvm/current/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 0):

Add `export NVM_SYMLINK_CURRENT=true` to your `.bashrc` before NVM-stuff. Then do `nvm use default` - symlink is created. Then add `$HOME/.nvm/current/bin` to your `PATH` in `.profile`.