# Environment Variables are not read by Intellij from ~/.bash_profile (Mac OS)

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I defined some Environment Variables in `~/.bash_profile`,like

```
export MVN_REPOSITORY_USERNAME=myself
export MVN_REPOSITORY_PASSWORD=myselfPwd
```

In my SBT plugin configuration `project/plugin.sbt` I use:

```
sys.env.get("MVN_REPOSITORY_USERNAME")
```

If I load my SBT-Project with ***IntelliJ***, they are **not set**.

However if I start the ***SBT-Console of IntelliJ***, they are **set**.

Is there any special configuration needed in *IntelliJ*?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385934/setting-environment-variables-via-launchd-conf-no-longer-works-in-os-x-yosemite#26586170 might help

Comment: You are probably better off storing the values in a dedicated (credentials) file and read that from SBT.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you source `~/.bash_profile`. This is a silly mistake, but an all too common one.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that with no success - meanwhile I have a working solution - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually with this SBT Setting it works:
intellij-sbt-settings.png[image]