# Git fliters smudge/clean not working in sourctree

Tags: git, filter, coding-style, atlassian-sourcetree

I have git smudge and git clean working using command line. But when I used sourcetree on the same repository to checkout and chekcin I dont see the filters working.
I added :

```
[filter "dater"]
    clean = TestClean.rb
```

in config.

Also added TestClean.rb in my path. I am using windows 10.

Comment: "working using command line" means : running `git add` from command line on a file which matches this filter triggers the "clean" action, correct ?

Comment: yes , when I do git add and git commit. I see clean filter running. But when using Sourcetree application to stage and commit, i dont see the filter running.

Answer (score 0):

Check first the actual environment used by SourceTree.

For instance, in this [bug report](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Staging-a-file-skips-Git-filter-quot-clean-quot-actions/qaq-p/673913#M18270) (yes, For Mac, not Windows, but the general point remains valid):

> Have a look at [`SRCTREE-3583`](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-3583).
>
> Sourcetree is most likely not picking up your script because it is launched as a service and will not pick up your changes to the PATH.
> You need to extend the PATH that your apps see, checkout "[Setting environment variables via launchd.conf no longer works in OS X Yosemite/El Capitan/macOS Sierra/Mojave?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385934/6309)" (mentioned in the issue) or search on how to extend `PATH` in OS X.

This is a Mac-specific issue, but in your case, you need to open [a terminal from SourceTree](https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/using-terminal-in-sourcetree-781398580.html), type "`env`", and check your environment variables compared to a regular CMD session where the filter works.

Not only the PATH should include your script, but it should also include ruby, in order to execute your script.