# When trying to start my Spring Boot application, I get google credentials needed even though I set them

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, google-cloud-platform

Right now, I have a spring boot application built with Maven. In IntelliJ, I'll run it and it will give me this error log. The last error says `The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials`. But I do have them. In my environment variables, I have `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` pointing to the path of my `credentials.json`.

```
.   ____          _            __ _ _
/\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
\\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
 '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
=========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
:: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.1.RELEASE)

2020-06-10 18:52:49.503  INFO 5100 --- [           main] c.t.n.sms.AdobeSmsBatchApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-06-10 18:52:51.232  INFO 5100 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2020-06-10 18:52:51.238  INFO 5100 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-06-10 18:52:51.314  INFO 5100 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 45ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
2020-06-10 18:52:51.869  INFO 5100 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=758dfa85-446e-37a3-9779-5d6170ddccf1
2020-06-10 18:52:52.908  INFO 5100 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-06-10 18:52:52.934  INFO 5100 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-06-10 18:52:52.934  INFO 5100 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.27]
2020-06-10 18:52:53.207  INFO 5100 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-06-10 18:52:53.208  INFO 5100 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3662 ms
2020-06-10 18:52:53.670  INFO 5100 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.a.c.GcpContextAutoConfiguration  : The default project ID is cio-notification-np-93822f
2020-06-10 18:52:53.696  INFO 5100 --- [           main] c.g.a.oauth2.ComputeEngineCredentials    : Failed to detect whether we are running on Google Compute Engine.
2020-06-10 18:52:53.699  WARN 5100 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.core.DefaultCredentialsProvider  : No core credentials are set. Service-specific credentials (e.g., spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.credentials.*) should be used if your app uses services that require credentials.
2020-06-10 18:52:53.731  INFO 5100 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 'pubsubPublisherThreadPool'
2020-06-10 18:52:53.815  INFO 5100 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 'pubsubSubscriberThreadPool'
2020-06-10 18:52:53.863  INFO 5100 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'pubSubAcknowledgementExecutor'
2020-06-10 18:52:54.110 ERROR 5100 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthContributorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthContributorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pubSubHealthIndicator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/pubsub/health/PubSubHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'pubSubHealthIndicator' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pubSubTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/pubsub/GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'pubSubTemplate' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pubSubSubscriberTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/pubsub/GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.core.subscriber.PubSubSubscriberTemplate]: Factory method 'pubSubSubscriberTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating the SubscriberStub
2020-06-10 18:52:54.150  INFO 5100 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-06-10 18:52:54.212 ERROR 5100 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
 at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:156) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
 at com.telus.notification.sms.AdobeSmsBatchApplication.main(AdobeSmsBatchApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
 at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:88) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthContributorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthContributorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pubSubHealthIndicator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/pubsub/health/PubSubHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'pubSubHealthIndicator' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pubSubTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/pubsub/GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'pubSubTemplate' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pubSubSubscriberTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/pubsub/GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.core.subscriber.PubSubSubscriberTemplate]: Factory method 'pubSubSubscriberTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating the SubscriberStub
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:645) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:625) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthContributorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthContributorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pubSubHealthIndicator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/pubsub/health/PubSubHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'pubSubHealthIndicator' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pubSubTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/pubsub/GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'pubSubTemplate' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pubSubSubscriberTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/pubsub/GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.core.subscriber.PubSubSubscriberTemplate]: Factory method 'pubSubSubscriberTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating the SubscriberStub
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 ... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthContributorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthContributorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pubSubHealthIndicator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/pubsub/health/PubSubHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'pubSubHealthIndicator' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pubSubTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/pubsub/GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'pubSubTemplate' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pubSubSubscriberTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/pubsub/GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.core.subscriber.PubSubSubscriberTemplate]: Factory method 'pubSubSubscriberTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating the SubscriberStub
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:787) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
... 54 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthContributorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthContributorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pubSubHealthIndicator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/pubsub/health/PubSubHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'pubSubHealthIndicator' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pubSubTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/pubsub/GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'pubSubTemplate' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pubSubSubscriberTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/pubsub/GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.core.subscriber.PubSubSubscriberTemplate]: Factory method 'pubSubSubscriberTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating the SubscriberStub
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:645) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
... 74 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthContributorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pubSubHealthIndicator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/pubsub/health/PubSubHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'pubSubHealthIndicator' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pubSubTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/pubsub/GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'pubSubTemplate' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pubSubSubscriberTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/pubsub/GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.core.subscriber.PubSubSubscriberTemplate]: Factory method 'pubSubSubscriberTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating the SubscriberStub
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 ... 88 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pubSubHealthIndicator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/pubsub/health/PubSubHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'pubSubHealthIndicator' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pubSubTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/pubsub/GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'pubSubTemplate' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pubSubSubscriberTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/pubsub/GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.core.subscriber.PubSubSubscriberTemplate]: Factory method 'pubSubSubscriberTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating the SubscriberStub
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:787) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
... 89 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pubSubTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/pubsub/GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'pubSubTemplate' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pubSubSubscriberTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/pubsub/GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.core.subscriber.PubSubSubscriberTemplate]: Factory method 'pubSubSubscriberTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating the SubscriberStub
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:787) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:528) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 ... 107 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pubSubSubscriberTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/pubsub/GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.core.subscriber.PubSubSubscriberTemplate]: Factory method 'pubSubSubscriberTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating the SubscriberStub
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:645) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:625) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 ... 121 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.core.subscriber.PubSubSubscriberTemplate]: Factory method 'pubSubSubscriberTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating the SubscriberStub
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 ... 135 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating the SubscriberStub
 at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.support.DefaultSubscriberFactory.createSubscriberStub(DefaultSubscriberFactory.java:277) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.core.subscriber.PubSubSubscriberTemplate.<init>(PubSubSubscriberTemplate.java:100) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.autoconfigure.pubsub.GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.pubSubSubscriberTemplate(GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.java:171) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 ... 136 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
 at com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.getDefaultCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:134) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.20.0.jar:na]
 at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:119) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.20.0.jar:na]
 at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:91) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.20.0.jar:na]
 at com.google.api.gax.core.GoogleCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(GoogleCredentialsProvider.java:67) ~[gax-1.54.0.jar:1.54.0]
 at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.core.DefaultCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:67) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-core-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
 at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:135) ~[gax-1.54.0.jar:1.54.0]
 at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.stub.GrpcSubscriberStub.create(GrpcSubscriberStub.java:263) ~[google-cloud-pubsub-1.103.0.jar:1.103.0]
 at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.support.DefaultSubscriberFactory.createSubscriberStub(DefaultSubscriberFactory.java:274) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
 ... 148 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What OS do you use? On macOS environment variables may be not visible from IntelliJ IDEA, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26586170/104891.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Windows 10

Comment: Did you logout/login after setting the environment variable?

Comment: To test if the environment variable is visible to your application: try manually reading the environment variable with `System.getenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS")` and see if it emits anything. Next test would be to pipe the output to the `File` constructor and see if your application can access the file (this can fail for all kinds of reasons like security permissions or improper escaping of slashes in the path variable)

Comment: Sometime you need to restart IntelliJ or you computer for taking into account the environment variable. In a terminal, you can test is your variable is set like this `echo %GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS%`

Answer (score 5):

If you use Intellij then open menu: Run/Edit Configurations. In the new panel, on left column click + to add Spring Boot application if you don't have one. When you have your Spring Boot Application on left column, on the right, click on Configuration Tab, look for Environment, expand it. Look for Environment variables, click edit icon on the right and add `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` and path to it. Save and run your application again. This will do the job.
If you build jar and run with java -jar, you must `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="path/to/key.json"`. Another approach: You also can set system-wide environment variables both on Mac and Windows to solve this issue.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using a service key file and the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`, you can also run the following command:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

You can then grant the access in the browser and the credentials will be saved in a file called `application_default_credentials.json` somewhere in your home directory.

The application will look for these credentials automatically if `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is not set. In most cases, this is the simpler approach.

Comment: Simple Approach . it is really helpful solution. Thanks