# Spring Boot with Cloud GCP Firestore, got error with Google Compute Engine GCP Credential, How to disable the error logs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

In our springboot project, we use only firestore, no other GCP services included

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-data-firestore</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

but we always got error with GCP Credidential, I want to disable that track, how to do it?

```
java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
```

In the application property we put as:

```
spring
   cloud:
      gcp:
        firestore:
            enabled: true
            project-id: my-firestore-project-id
            credentials:
                location: classpath:my-firestore-authentication-file-xxxx.json
```

I already tried to disabled as:

```
spring.cloud.gcp.logging.enabled=false
spring.cloud.gcp.trace.enabled=false
```

and still error, the error wont stop the application but it's disturb and how to disable that?

Comment: can you check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62320163/15774176 is it helpful?

Comment: @DivyaniYadav thanks, I aware that but I want to ignore the login as I don't use that service.