# Can't run Appium

Tags: macos, appium, pom.xml

I am trying to run a project with Appium but when I run it I am having this error:
[image]

And I have installed node and Appium. Appium on my desktop and on my node_modules[image]

And I have io.appium on my POM
[image]

I've been searching all weekend without any success, Can someone help on this?

Comment: Does it work in the terminal outside of IntelliJ IDEA? There could be some issue with the required binaries missing in your system `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: nop, on terminal y failing too. Well I got this on my .bash_profile

Comment: export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH=/Users/diego.j.magallon/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb 
export PATH=/Users/diego.j.magallon/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
export M2_HOME=/Users/diego.j.magallon/Desktop/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/diego.j.magallon/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS=$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/30.0.1
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/diego.j.magallon/Library/Android/sdk

Comment: Make sure a directory containing `node` binary is in `PATH` and you can run it from the terminal.

Comment: I added export NODE_JS_HOME=/usr/local/bin but is not working, I am running man `mvn clean install`but is not working

Comment: `npm install -g appium`

Comment: Issues persists  :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219559/discussion-between-diego-magallon-and-crazycoder).

Comment: I fixed the problem, I believe it was because I am using Catalina OS and .bash_profile is deprecated so I moved all my paths to .zshrc.
I only had to leave ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME on my bash_profile because somehow my project is reading those paths on the bash_profile file

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26586170/104891.