# Failed to run Python script from Java using Intellij

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea

I'm attempting to run a Python script using Java code in Intellij IDEA:

```
String commandString = "python /home/.../mypythonscript.py arg1 arg2";
try {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandString);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
} catch(IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
```

The Python script outputs a single String, and works great when I run it from my Ubuntu Linux terminal. However,  using the above Java to run the Python script returns an error message:

> ```
> Failed to run Python Script: Cannot run program "python": error=2, No such file or directory.
> ```

The file path is correct (the path and arguments I give are identical to what I used to run the Python script in the terminal), and I've set the script permissions to 777. In Intellij, I've also gone to File>Settings>Appearance & Behavior>Path Variables and added a path to the folder that contains the Python script (it's being held in a folder for Pycharm projects). However, I'm still getting the error.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What OS do you use? Terminal environment can be different from the environment visible to the UI apps, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26586170/104891. You can type `env` in the Terminal tool window in IntelliJ IDEA to print the variables and double check that `python` binary is in `PATH`.

Comment: I'm using an Ubuntu virtual machine (by terminal, I mean the Ubuntu terminal, not the terminal in Intellij). In reference to my previous comment, which I've now deleted, I updated python to python3. Using process.waitFor(), I realized that the script is not running, or is encountering an error when it runs, so the issue persists, though it no longer shows an error.

Comment: If there is no error shown, then the issue is completely different. Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including the Python script that you are trying to run from Java code.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, that's a good point-- thanks. I've rolled back the question to its previous version, to assist others with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more experienced Java developer friend of mine who doesn't have an account figured out the problem, the solution to which I'm posting here for anyone encountering a similar issue in the future:

The script was written in Python3, but the code I used:

```
String commandString = "python /home/.../mypythonscript.py arg1 arg2";
```

is for Python 2. It should have been written:

```
String commandString = "python3 /home/.../mypythonscript.py arg1 arg2";
```