# gradle -version is displayed as gradle command not found

Tags: java, macos, gradle

As an initial setup I have installed jdk 15.0.2 and gradle 6.7 in my machine.
First I installed jdk 15.0.2 and added JAVA_HOME path in mac terminal using below code

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk15.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home"
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Then I installed gradle 6.7 and added GRADLE_HOME path in mac terminal using below code

```
export GRADLE_HOME="/opt/gradle/gradle-6.7/bin"
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle/gradle-6.7/bin
```

Both JAVA_HOME and GRADLE_HOME are placed under the same name PATH
Now while checking the java -version it is getting correct version and while checking

```
gradle -version
```

it is getting

```
gradle: command not found
```

Is there any way to solve this issue

Comment: Show us `echo $PATH` before you run Gradle

Comment: Simply exporting variables doesn't make them persistent across runs. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385934/setting-environment-variables-via-launchd-conf-no-longer-works-in-os-x-yosemite)

Comment: Note: if you use sdkman or homebrew, your PATH already would be correct

Comment: echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin