# How to find a valid path to julia.exe

Tags: path, julia, visual-studio-code

I try to use julia-1.6 with VScode, but I cannot find a path to the executable.
When I try to change the working directory via the julia prompt to the executable, I get an error message saying it's not a directory:

```
julia> cd("/Users/jjdegruijter/bin/julia")
```

Can anybody tell how to do it properly?

Comment: Don't you want `cd("/Users/jjdegruijter/bin/")` instead? `/Users/jjdegruijter/bin/julia` is the actual binary and not a directory.

Answer (score 3):

To get the path to your Julia executable, from the REPL, do:

```
joinpath(Sys.BINDIR, "julia")
```

You can start a REPL by just running `julia` from the terminal, or by pressing `Alt-J Alt-O` in VS Code (you can also instead type `Ctrl-Shift-P`, then choose `Julia: Start REPL` from that list).

Or, you can also directly run the above command from the terminal without starting a REPL: `julia -e 'println(joinpath(Sys.BINDIR, "julia"))'`.

If you just want to change working directory to the directory containing the executable (though I'm not sure why you'd want that here):

```
cd(Sys.BINDIR)
```

Comment: I do not know how to start REPL. When I put joinpath... in my terminal I get syntaxerror unexpected token 'Sys.BINDIR,'.

Comment: You mention typing `cd("/Users/jjdegruijter/bin/julia")` at a `julia> ` prompt in the question. Wherever you get that `julia> ` prompt, that's an REPL.

Comment: Or from the terminal, you can try running `julia -e 'println(joinpath(Sys.BINDIR, "julia"))'`.

Comment: I've added in instructions about accessing the REPL to the answer, please take a look.

Comment: When I run "julia -e ...." from the terminal, then I get " julia: command not found"

Comment: My problem is that my setting to the julia executable path in VScode still does not work. The last version I tried is: "julia.executablePath": "/Applications/julia-1.6.app/Contents/Resources/julia

Comment: @JdG You mention "the julia prompt" in the question. How did you get that?

Comment: I got the julia prompt by clicking on the julia executable in the bin.

Comment: Are you able to click on the julia executable again and get the prompt? If so, please do that and then run the `joinpath` command given in the answer. If for some reason you're not able to do that, [we can discuss this further in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241837/q-70985429).

Comment: I've run the joinpath command, and put the path that was returned by the prompt in the VScode setting. It didn't help. I got "Could not start the Julia language server. Make sure the configuration setting julia.executablePath points to the Julia binary."

Comment: Fyi I work with OS version 10.11.6

Comment: You might have luck setting `PATH` to have the Julia path (the `Sys.BINDIR` result alone, without the `"julia"` at the end); see [this answer for an example of modifying `PATH`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26586170/8127). After setting that, delete the `executablePath` setting you added, restart the system, and try VSCode again. But at this point I suspect something may have gone wrong with your VS Code Julia extension installation itself. If the above doesn't work, please ask this question on the [Julia Discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/) with screenshots and version information.